# Finding the eigenvalues of the transpose map.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, diagonalization

The question is as follows:

Define $T : M_n(\mathbb{R}) → M_n(\mathbb{R})$ by $T(A) = A^t$. Prove that T has two distinct eigenvalues, and that its eigenvectors span $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

I am completely stuck on this. I have an intuitive idea of why it is correct but no proof. I have tried explaining how 1 and -1 are the only values that make the determinant of $A-tI$ equal to $0$ by using ideas about addition and swapping of columns using EROs. I've tried to show it is diagonalizable, and therefore has enough linearly independent vectors to span $M_n(\mathbb{R})$, all to no avail. If somebody could help me with this I'd be extremely thankful.

Comment: Hint: $T^2 = \operatorname{id}$.  From there I'd imagine there must be an answer somewhere on this site about general linear operators $T$ satisfying $T^2 = \operatorname{id}$ which you could apply.

Comment: Past that, the most interesting part would be finding the dimensions of the eigenspaces (and in particular showing each eigenspace is nontrivial, so 1 and -1 are actually eigenvalues and not just extraneous solutions).

Comment: For all matrices you can write $A=\frac{A+A^t}{2}+\frac{A-A^t}{2}$. Now check that $\frac{A+A^t}{2}$ and $\frac{A+A^t}{2}+\frac{A-A^t}{2}$ are eigenvectors of $T$ corresponding to the eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$ respectively, and it is very easy to have them non-zero.

Comment: Come to think of it, that would make it easy to calculate $\operatorname{tr}(T)$ and $\operatorname{det}(T)$.  Which could be a nice problem to pose independently.  (You could also solve that problem by noting $T$ can easily be expressed as a permutation matrix from a very concrete permutation on $n^2$.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

What is minimal polynomial of the transpose map in $M_n(\mathbf R)$? Which criteria for diagonalisability do you know?